# javascript mapping from response data

Tags: javascript

I have a laravel app where I'm taking the response data and compounding duplicates into a comments array like so:

```
const dataMap = response.data.reduce((map, { taskt_id, comment_name, comment, ...extra }) => {
      let item = (map.has(taskt_id) ? map : map.set(taskt_id, { ...extra, comments: [] })).get(taskt_id)
      return item.comments.push({ comment_name, comment }), map

    }, new Map())
```

This has been working perfectly, but now I have another data set coming back in my response data that has multiple records as well (one category but multiple category details) and when I use this method, it no longer works and my new categories array is empty:

```
 const dataMap = response.data.reduce((map, { taskt_id, comment_name, comment, category, category_detail, ...extra }) => {
      let item = (map.has(taskt_id) ? map : map.set(taskt_id, { ...extra, comments: [], categories: [] })).get(taskt_id)
      return item.comments.push({ comment_name, comment }), map
      return item.categories.push({ category, category_detail }), map

    }, new Map())
```

So maybe I'm adding another array to this in the wrong way, but how can I add more arrays to this mapping in the way that my working comments version is behaving?

Comment: Why do you have `return` twice?

Comment: when you use `return`, the function execution stops, so the code after the first `return` isn't reached

Comment: In my opinion, using the comma operator like that just leads to confusion. It's "clever" which is the opposite of "maintainable".

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'd also add that the one line which has *four operations* preceding it is also bad. I guess it depends on how you define "operation", of course, you could also say there is six operations.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this was just the way I was originally shown to do it, but it was only with one array in mind, which is obviously my problem now in needing more than one array ( to your correct point of maintainability)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the map after the item.comments.push and discarding the rest.

You could replace this:

```
return item.comments.push({ comment_name, comment }), map
return item.categories.push({ category, category_detail }), map
```

with this:

```
item.comments.push({ comment_name, comment })
item.categories.push({ category, category_detail })
return map
```

So you add the comments and categories to your item and then return the map.